# Oracle DB : What is difference between spfile and init.ora file?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have tried to understand through [oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_4.htm) but could not get it properly Any body please explain.
What is difference between spfile and init.ora file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

init.ora

- init.ora or the pfile(parameter file) is a simple text file which can be updated by a standard editor like vi 
  which contains the various initialization parameters used while starting a database instance.
  Here is a sample init.ora file:

db_cache_size = 176000M

db_2k_cache_size = 2048M

db_16k_cache_size = 99000M

db_keep_cache_size = 600000M

db_recycle_cache_size = 64000M

shared_pool_size = 14000M

- We need to restart the database after editing the init.ora using a text editor  so that the changes can come into effect.
- If we want to start a remote db we need a local pfile.
- RMAN(Recovery manager) which helps in data backup recovery process does not keep the backup of pfile or init.ora file.

spfile

- The Oracle spfile is a binary representation of the text based init.ora file or pfile( parameter file)  which contains the various initialization
  parameters used while starting a database instance.Came into existence in and after Oracle 9i.
- We do not edit this file using an editor as it is a binary file and may get corrupted and which may lead to your database instance not starting rather 
  it is altered by using the `alter system` query.
  An example of editing a spfile  :
  `ALTER SYSTEM SET open_cursors=300 SCOPE=SPFILE;`
- The changes come into effect after running the `Alter system query` and we do not need to restart the database.
- We do not need a local copy in case of spfile if we need to start a remote database.
- As this file is maintained by the server the parameters are validated before they are accepted.
- RMAN keeps the backup of spfile.
- By default our database uses pfile to start we can change that and create a spfile from a pfile or init.ora file by using the following query and we don't even need to restart the db.

  `sqlplus / as sydba;
  CREATE SPFILE FROM PFILE='/u01/oracle/dbs/init.ora;`

Answer (score 2):

The difference between init.ora and spfile.

- init.ora and spfile both contains Database parameters info. With
  spfile you can set Oracle database settings with the ALTER SYSTEM
  command that is used in sqlplus to add/Modify/delete settings.
  However for init.ora you edit it as a text file because init.ora 
  saved in the format of ASCII.
- init.ora info is read by oracle engine at the time of database
  instance . in spfile modifications can applicable without restarting
  oracle database.
- When an Oracle database is started, the process will always use
  spfile.ora, if it exists.  If the spfile.ora is not found, the
  init.ora would be used on startup.